# Parse RTF file into NSArray - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, rtf, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse and English Dictionary from an RTF file into an array.

I originally had it working, but I'm not sure why it isn't now.

In the dictionary, each word is separated by a new line (\n). My code so far is:

```
//loading the dictionary into the file and pull the content from the file into memory
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"wordList.rtf"];

//convert the bytes from the file into a string
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                             length:[data length]
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//split the string around newline characters to create an array
NSArray *englishDictionary = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

When I try and NSLog it, it just comes up with (null)...

I've already looked at: [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

But couldn't get the answer by Yoon Lee working properly. It prints out with two back slashes at the end as well as lots of unnecessary stuff at the start!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Try using a plain text (txt) file instead of rtf. RTF files contain formatting information about the text as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a plain text (txt) file instead of rtf. RTF files contain formatting information about the text as well. Thats the unnecessary stuff that you see after reading the content.

Comment: how would I convert an rtf document into a txt document? Can I just change the file ending in finder? Would that work? I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: If you are on a mac, open the file in TextEdit and press Cmd+Shift+T (this will convert it to plain text and remove all formatting) then save as a txt.