# Swift code to produce a number of possible anagrams from a selected word

Tags: ios, swift, anagram

I've attempted to research ways to take a given word and calculate the number of possible anagrams a user can make from that word eg an 8 letter word such as snowbanks has 5 eight letter possibilities, 25 seven letter possibilities, etc (those are made up numbers). My initial plan would be to iterate over a dictionary list and check each of the words to see if it is an anagram of the word in question as I've seen suggested in other places.

[Rearrange Letters from Array and check if arrangement is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859238/rearrange-letters-from-array-and-check-if-arrangement-is-in-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

seemed very promising, except that it is in objective C and when I tried to convert it to Swift using Swiftify I couldn't get it to work as shown below:

```
    func findAnagrams() -> Set<AnyHashable>? {
        let nineCharacters = [unichar](repeating: 0, count: 8)
        let anagramKey = self.anagramKey()
        // make sure this word is not too long/short.
        if anagramKey == nil {
            return nil
        }
        (anagramKey as NSString?)?.getCharacters(nineCharacters, range: NSRange)
        let middleCharPos = Int((anagramKey as NSString?)?.range(of: (self as NSString).substring(with: NSRange)).location ?? 0)
        var anagrams = Set<AnyHashable>()
        // 0x1ff means first 9 bits set: one for each character
        for i in 0...0x1ff {
            // skip permutations that do not contain the middle letter
            if (i & (1 << middleCharPos)) == 0 {
                continue
            }
            var length: Int = 0
            var permutation = [unichar](repeating: 0, count: 9)
            for bit in 0...9 {
                if true {
                    permutation[length] = nineCharacters[bit]
                    length += 1
                }
            }
            if length < 4 {
                continue
            }
            let permutationString = String(permutation)
            let matchingAnagrams = String.anagramMap()[permutationString] as? [Any]
            for word: String? in matchingAnagrams {
                anagrams.insert(word)
            }
        }
        return anagrams
    }

    class func anagramMap() -> [AnyHashable: Any]? {
        var anagramMap: [AnyHashable: Any]
        if anagramMap != nil {
            return anagramMap
        }
        // this file is present on Mac OS and other unix variants
        let allWords = try? String(contentsOfFile: "/usr/share/dict/words", encoding: .utf8)
        var map = [AnyHashable: Any]()
        autoreleasepool {
            allWords?.enumerateLines(invoking: {(_ word: String?, _ stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?) -> Void in
                let key = word?.anagramKey()
                if key == nil {
                    return
                }
                var keyWords = map[key] as? [AnyHashable]
                if keyWords == nil {
                    keyWords = [AnyHashable]()
                    map[key] = keyWords
                }
                if let aWord = word {
                    keyWords?.append(aWord)
                }
            })
        }
        anagramMap = map
        return anagramMap
    }

    func anagramKey() -> String? {
        let lowercaseWord = word.lowercased()
        // make sure to take the length *after* lowercase. it might change!
        let length: Int = lowercaseWord.count
        // in this case we're only interested in anagrams 4 - 9 characters long
        if length < 3 || length > 9 {
            return nil
        }
        let sortedWord = [unichar](repeating: 0, count: length)
        (lowercaseWord as NSString).getCharacters(sortedWord, range: NSRange)
        qsort_b(sortedWord, length, MemoryLayout<unichar>.size, {(_ aPtr: UnsafeRawPointer?, _ bPtr: UnsafeRawPointer?) -> Int in
            let a = Int(unichar(aPtr))
            let b = Int(unichar(bPtr))
            return b - a
        })
        return String(describing: sortedWord)
    }




func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}

}
```

I've also tried the following in an attempt to just produce a list of words that I could iterate over to check for anagrams (I have working code that checks guesses vs the main word to check for anagrams) but I wasn't able to get them to work, possibly because they require a file to be copied to the app, since I was under the impression that the phone has a dictionary preloaded that I could use for words (although I may be mistaken):

```
var allTheWords = try? String(contentsOfFile: "/usr/share/dict/words", encoding: .utf8)
    for line: String? in allTheWords?.components(separatedBy: "\n") ?? [String?]() {
        print("\(line ?? "")")
        print("Double Fail \(allTheWords)")
    }
```

and

```
    if let wordsFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dict", ofType: nil) {
        do {
            let wordsString = try String(contentsOfFile: wordsFilePath)

            let wordLines = wordsString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines)

            let randomLine = wordLines[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordLines.count)))]

            print(randomLine)

        } catch { // contentsOfFile throws an error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

I looked at UIReferenceLibraryViewController as well in an attempt to use it to produce a list of words instead of defining a selected word, but the following isn't a valid option.

```
let words = UIReferenceLibraryViewController.enumerated
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "My initial plan would be to iterate over a dictionary list and check each of the words to see if it is an anagram of the word in question" Wouldn't it be better the other way, i.e. to generate all possible anagrams and look them up in the dictionary?

Comment: "when I tried to convert it to Swift using Swiftify I couldn't get it to work as shown below" Wouldn't it b better to convert it to Swift using your brain?

Comment: I was unsure of the better method of checking words. For a 8 letter word the number of possible 8 letter combinations (assuming no repeated letters) is just over 40k, just over 5k for each combination of 7 letter words, so that would be another 40k for each of the 8 possible combinations, etc. The following site shows the equation for calculating the number of possible letter combinations: https://gmatclub.com/forum/how-many-different-anagrams-can-you-make-for-the-word-mathem-170485.html

Comment: No, you can do that if YOU like. You didn’t explain what “I couldn’t get it to work” means, and I don’t think it’s my job to figure that out.

Comment: Oooh I guess you’re right about starting with the dictionary!